# c# and xml with recursive function

Tags: c#, xml

i have an xml file:

```
<node ID="1" query="query 1" dbQuery="aaa">
    <node ID="2" query="query 2" dbQuery="bbb"></node>
    <node ID="3" query="query 3" dbQuery="aaa"></node>
    <node ID="4" query="query 4" dbQuery="ccc"></node>
        <node ID="5" query="query 5" dbQuery="ddd">
            <node ID="6" query="query 6" dbQuery="eee"></node>
        </node>
</node>
```

and i try it to read with this function:

```
private void ProcessaSottoNodi(XmlNode node)
{
    if (node.HasChildNodes)
    {
        foreach (XmlNode cNode in node.ChildNodes)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", cNode.Name);
            foreach (XmlAttribute attr in cNode.Attributes)
               Console.WriteLine("{0}", attr.Name + " = " + attr.InnerText);

            Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------");
        ProcessaSottoNodi(cNode);
        }
    }
}
```

and that's fine, but if I change the XML file by adding "TextB", "TextC", "TextF" is in error function

```
<node ID="1" query="query 1" dbQuery="aaa">
    <node ID="2" query="query 2" dbQuery="bbb">TextB</node>
    <node ID="3" query="query 3" dbQuery="ccc">TextC</node>
    <node ID="4" query="query 4" dbQuery="ddd">TextD</node>
        <node ID="5" query="query 5" dbQuery="eee">
            <node ID="6" query="query 6" dbQuery="fff">TextF</node>
        </node>
</node>
```

how to change my function to be able to read the attributes and InnerText without error?

Thank

Answer (score 0):

to get the innerText of the XL-Tag you'll need to do something like this:

```
Console.Write(cNode.InnerText);
```

The code I added will print out the InnerText of cNode where cNode is your XmlNode-Object

Answer (score 0):

the problem is not in the Console.WriteLine but

```
foreach (XmlAttribute attr in cNode.Attributes)
```

Answer (score 0):

`InnerText` is not a property of an Attribute, but a `Node`.